What are the general conditions for the existence of solutions to this differential equation involving a Lie derivative?
Suppose I am given a vector field $Y$. What I would like to know is the general conditions under which
$\mathcal{L}_{Y} X = - Y$
has a solution $X$ (where $X$ is another vector field). I am certain that it is generally not unique as one should always be able to add something "homogeneous" like
$\mathcal{L}_{Y} Z = 0$
for a vector field $Z$.
Edit:  After a suggestion in the comments, I will ask further - what initial conditions make the solution vector field X unique?

It'd be also interesting to ask what initial conditions will make the solution unique.

First let's take a chart with coordinates $x_1,...,x_n$ in which $Y=\frac{\partial}{\partial x_1}$. There is always such a chart around each point. Then with
$$Z=\sum_{i=1}^n a_i \frac{\partial}{\partial x_i}$$
from $\mathcal{L}_YZ=-Y$ we get
$$\frac{\partial a_1}{\partial x_1}=1$$
$$\frac{\partial a_i}{\partial x_1}=0$$
for each $i>1$. Given the value of all the $a_i$s restricted to the hypersurface $x_1=c$ there is a unique solution $Z$ satisfying the DE.
I don't see an obvious way to extend this local story to a global one. For instance, local solutions may not patch together to make a global one, and it is not clear what a good boundary condition might be in the global case.  But it may well be possible to make sense of such a thing.

You might as well state the solution to the equations you wrote. From there it is straightforward to construct examples for which no global solution exists and those for which global solutions do exist.
